# Find integer solutions of $xy=-1$ (using only elementary ring theory).

Tags: ring-theory

I know the answer is obvious: In $\mathbb{Z}$ the only solutions of $xy=-1$ are $x=-y=1$ and $x=-y=-1$.
My problem is that I want to formally prove it and I don't know how to write it. Where do you even begin for such a trivial statement?

**Edit: I would like to prove it viewing $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring. This is, just using the sum and product of integers. No order, no absolute value, etc...**

Answer (score 3):

if $xy=-1$, then we we have $|x||y|=1$, that is we must have $|x|=1$ and $|y|=1$.

Also, determinining $x$ would completely determine $y$.

Hence we only need to examine what happends when $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: Do you think is possible to prove it using just the sum and product defined in the integers? I mean, viewing $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring.

Comment: I think Z is defined so that 1 and -1 are the only units by definition.  I think.

Answer (score 2):

If xy = -1, then x = $\frac{-1}{y}$. If x is an integer, y must divide -1. Therefore, y = $\pm$1, which implies x $\mp$1.

Comment: Do you think is possible to prove it using just the sum and product defined in the integers? I mean, viewing $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring.

Comment: @Cabex This nearly does what you want, it can be rephrased to say that the only units in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't get it, we can't divide in $\mathbb{Z}$. Isn't assuming $y$ has an inverse, or viewing the equation outside the integers?

Comment: (xy)$^2$ = x$^2$y$^2$ = 1. Since x, y $\in \mathbb{Z}$, this implies that x$^2$ = y$^2$ = 1. So, x is it's own inverse. Thus x = $\pm$ 1.

Comment: Right! Using idempotents... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers (same can be done for negative, or just use absolute value):

If $x >1$ and $y>1$, then $xy>1$. So either $x =1$ or $y=1$. If $x=1$, then $1 \cdot y=1$, so $y=1$. If $y=1$, then $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively.

If $x $ or $y $ is $0$, $xy=0$.

Otherwise, $|x|\ge 1$ and $|y|\ge 1$. If $|x|>1$ then $|xy|=|y||x|>|y|\ge 1$.  So we must have $|x|=1$.  And $1=|xy|=|x||y|=|y|$ so $|x|=|y|=1$.

Of the four options only $x=y=1;x=y=-1$ work.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  I see someone else had the same idea.  I'll delete when I get to an application that let's me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $xy=-1$, then $-xy=1$, so $x$ and $y$ are units (by definition).  Since the only units in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$, we can check which combinations result in a product of $-1$.